# How Append data to same line of text file

Tags: bash

How append data to same line of text file ?
Case is first part is output of command and another is my  special text, for e.g with code $ `date >> file.txt && echo -n "new data" >> file.txt`, here first output of date is stored first in file and text "new data" on new line, If I change the sequence of code for e.g -$ `echo "new data ">> file.txt && date >> file.txt` then it apeend the data on same line but I wanna append the date output first then the special text. How can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `date` command automatically adds the newline at the end of the command. To remove this newline you could do:

```
date | tr -d '\n' >> file.txt && echo -n "new data" >> file.txt
```

This will remove any newlines from the date output.

Comment: thnx, It also works

Answer (score 4):

try

```
echo $(date) "new data" >> file.txt
```

where

- `$( )` substituion will strip new line of date.

Comment: As long as "new data" doesn't contain anything which has meaning as a `date` formatting code, `date +"%c new data" >>file.txt` might be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with removing newline character using substitution.

```
$ d=$(date)
$ echo -n $d >> file
$ echo " <- this is date" >> file
$ cat file
Mon Feb 4 07:08:21 CET 2019 <- this is date
$
```

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yeah, I found it too. I thought that ${d:-2} will strip last character but now, I don't know. :/

Comment: thnx,It Works also

Answer (score 1):

Another option, for the case where "new data" is static:

```
printf '%s new data\n' "$(date)" >> file.txt
```

For the situation where "new data" could vary:

```
printf '%s %s\n' "$(date)" "${newdatavar}" >> file.txt
```